# Rails server not starting in debug mode, saying I need to set deprecation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running rails 3.1.3 with ruby 1.9.3p0

My gemfile:

```
gem 'rails'

group :development do 
  gem 'ruby-debug19'
end
```

When I run `rails server -debugger` I get:

rails server -debugger
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.3 application starting in bugger on http://0.0.0.0:3000

And then it just seems to have shutdown, the server doesnt' respond as if it was not started.

Before I was getting an error saying I didn't set the deprecation, so I had to create a file:

```
environments/bugger.rb

MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

end
```

And now it doesnt' show any error in the terminal.

Comment: I think some gems were missing.. So, please try this command bundle install

Comment: I really want to upvote this question for creating an environment called `bugger`…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should be --debugger (2 dashes). Ruby is parsing what you are doing as -d (daemonize) and -e bugger (set rails env to bugger)

Comment: (unrelated to this question/answer): See this post about meging accounts: [How tro merge 2 accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Comment: That was one of my more amusing bugs of today.